# Adding MAKEFLAGS from MPC(The Makefile, Project, and Workspace Creator)

Tags: c++, c++11, makefile

I am using MPC to generate my makefiles. I generate successfully the Makefile but when I run make I get the following error:

> error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.

**My question is, how to add build flags (eg:`-std=c++11`) to my MPC?**

For completion here is my MPC file:

```
project(Makefile) : dcpsexe, dcps_tcp {
   requires += no_opendds_safety_profile
   exename   = start
   after    += *idl

   TypeSupport_Files {
     Communication.idl
   }

   Source_Files {
     ListenerReader.cpp
     Publisher.cpp
     Subscriber.cpp
     main.cpp    
   }
}
```

Comment: Which MPC project type are you generating?

Comment: @JohnnyWillemsen gnuace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done through the `$ACE_ROOT/include/makeinclude/platform_macros.GNU` file. Add a line with `c++11=1` to the top of this file, that will enable C++11 support for the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to enabling C++11 (or later) [specifically for the *platform*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43386447/1312382) this can be achieved on project basis, too, e.g.

```
specific(make) {
    compile_flags += -std=c++20
}
```

`make` has been selected according to [MPC documentation](http://snaewe.github.io/MPC/docs/html/MakeProjectCreator.html#projectSpecific), I haven't tested myself (but did for a MSVC project where it worked seamlessly) – *possibly* the undocumented `gcc` (or `clang`) compiler options might be supported as well (the equally undocumented `vs2019` and `vs2022` ones definitely *are* so), you'll have to try yourself...